# Integrating IM applications with outlook 2013, user's presence not enabled in Contact Card

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2013, lync-2013, lync-client-sdk

I have implemented the IM Client (32 bits) for Outlook 2013 (64 bits) as per article "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900715.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396".
I have implemented the COM class by UCOfficeIntegration. Below link has one example as well and my class implementation is working well with this example. 
Link: [_IContactsAndGroupsCallback.OnLookUp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33830124/icontactsandgroupscallback-onlookup/33954198#33954198)

Outlook is calling below APIs to IM Client and IM Client is also responding with valid data. But Outlook couldn't enable the user's presence with chat, audio call, video call in Outlook Contact Card.

Called APIs from Outlook to IM Client? 
IContactManager.GetContactByUri
IContact.CanStart
IContact.GetContactInformation
IContactManager.CreateSubscription
IContactSubscription.AddContact
IContactSubscription.Subscribe
IContact.BatchGetContactInformation
IContact.Settings

If these APIs are called from Outlook then why Outlook is not enabling/updating the user's presence in Outlook Contact Card? 
 Will anybody please help to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with the way you test you IM Client. One thing you should do is always start IM Client before outlook. If still problem persist then check following thing :

1. UnifiedCommunicationType should be ucUnifiedCommunicationEnabled.
2. If you face this issue after second reboot of IM client then check the UpAndRunning Key whether you make it to 0 and then 2 when your IM application starts. This is what I have experience. You can check this.