# out process COM server crash when client sets up event listener

Tags: c#, com

IMP.exe is my out process COM server.
It includes Microsoft.Office.Uc.dll.

TestIMP.exe is my COM client.Code is the same with the link [_IContactsAndGroupsCallback.OnLookUp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33830124/icontactsandgroupscallback-onlookup/33954198#33954198)

Microsoft.Office.Uc.dll and IMP.exe are written to Registry successfully.

When the line below is executed, a crash occurs.

```
officeIntegration.OnShuttingDown += officeIntegration_OnShuttingDown;
```

[crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk81D.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash is because the version of my Framework is not suitable.The version I used is 3.5. After I upgraded to Framework 4.0, it works.